# Library/android-sdk-mac_86 - can I delete this?

Tags: android

What is the `~/Library/android-sdk-mac_86` folder I have on my file system. The reason I ask is that there's already a `~/Library/Android` folder with loads of Android SDKs on my file system.

The `~/Library/android-sdk-mac_86` folder comes to 5.5GB so, if it's not used, I'd like to delete it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Android SDK Manager it should tell you which path it's actually using at the top. It's probably safe to delete the folder that's not being used.

[image: Screenshot of Android SDK Manager. SDK Path is shown in top left corner.]